# Capability to set Ethernet SFD field

Tags: real-time, ethernet

For over 40 years, Ethernet frames started with a 7-byte preamable (all 0x55) followed by a 1-byte SFD  (Start Frame Delimiter, 0xD1). Now this is changing with the Ethernet TSN extensions, where the SFD field can have different values, and the the preamble can be only 6 bytes. See background on https://iebmedia.com/technology/tsn/tsn-technology-basics-of-ethernet-frame-preemption-part-2/

Now I'm looking for an Ethernet controller (PC, laptob, PI) which allows for a user application to change this. Having looked around, found none so far, but perhaps that it is to be expected, all Ethernet probably have the preamble/SFD fixed, since it was so specified for the last 40 years.

Reason I'm asking is, the first TSN equipment is now coming on the market (i.e. switches) but what counterpart do they communicate with? Hope it can work with existing hardware, some how.

Hoped that I could set the necessary configuration with ethtool, but found none.